# Duplicating style from another map when it's locked using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, style, template

Print Layout from a template with two maps of the same layer, but different styling.

My code perfectly works for the first map:

```
#1
#getting map ID from the layout
map1 = layout.itemById('mapId_1')
#changing layer styling value
layer.renderer().setClassAttribute('attr_1')
#Locking map style
map1.setKeepLayerSet(True)
map1.setKeepLayerStyles(True)
```

But the same code for the second map doesn't work.

It's making two maps with second layer styling value `attr_2`.

```
#2
#getting map ID from the layout
map2 = layout.itemById('mapId_2')
#changing layer styling
layer.renderer().setClassAttribute('attr_2')
#Locking map style
map2.setKeepLayerSet(True)
map2.setKeepLayerStyles(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It's just the next thing:

```
map1.setLayers([points,layer,basemap])
```

and

```
map2.setLayers([points,layer,basemap])
```

Before I was thinkin that it would refresh/save it the same way as with GUI.